# Rail 7 - host - no image - development - activestorage - turbo

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage, ruby-on-rails-7, turbo

I use broadcast_update_to in rake task. When I use task from console

```
rake my:task:start
```

images are displayed and URL is like this:

`http://localhost:3000/rails/active_storage/representations/redirect/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBFdz09IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--3833f3108a319f5d3bfb749027e53fc1ebdc8bc1/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaDdCem9MWm05eWJXRjBTU0lJYW5CbkJqb0dSVlE2RTNKbGMybDZaVjkwYjE5bWFXeHNXd2RwSG1rZSIsImV4cCI6bnVsbCwicHVyIjoidmFyaWF0aW9uIn19--1e1f53dc4dc279946af9ca0013ce3a1fd9567bf8/focia1%20(2).jpg*`

but when I refresh view from **rake task by crontab ( gem whenever )**, **images are not displayed.**

First I have example.org( Rails generates for script started for example by crontab `example.org` ) link but then I set in `development.rb`:

```
Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:host] = 'localhost:3000'
```

and still nothing ...

so I add this also in `production.rb` - and then example.org was replaced by localhost:3000 - but images are still not displayed.